# A common verb to describe someone's act when he/she eats eagerly and pleasantly

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, verbs

I'm going to describe someone who eats usually eagerly and pleasantly so that it appetizes others, makes them feel good, and makes them want to eat the dish themselves. How shall I imply that in everyday speech?
The only way that seems to be idiomatic is:

> - (S)he [devours](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/devour) food.

Is there a better way to say it?

PS: I need a verb not an adjective.

Comment: **devour** doesn't mean eating pleasantly or taking your time to get the taste in your mouth. It means to eat rather hungrily and quickly. Also, _He/she devours his/her food_. Not any and every food, but __their__ food.

Comment: I added a link @DhanishthaGhosh. PLease have a look on the dictionary definition.

Comment: I saw it already before posting the comment here, just to be sure. It can happen that the word might mean different and I don't know it yet. But it seems like the meaning tells the act of devouring means to _eat something eagerly and hurriedly_. If you wish to express only that one feeling of eagerness, then you can go forward and use the word _devour_. However, it definitely isn't a pleasant way of eating.

Comment: I doubt if there is a single verb for 'eating so as to make others want the same dish'. You would have to spell it out in more detail, for instance 'X appeared to be relishing his meal, making the others realise how hungry they were'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kate has the word in her comment:  "Relish" meaning "to enjoy the taste of something" (and figuratively "to enjoy doing something")

It doesn't explictly mean "... and so made others hungry", but you can easily add that to your sentence.

> She relished her meal, and everyone's stomachs began to rumble.

Also as a noun (perhaps with deliberate ambiguity) as in the famous first sentence of the third chapter of Ulysses:

> Mr Leopold Bloom ate with relish the inner organs of beasts and fowls.